# conditioned explode in presto\spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, presto

I have table with with this structure:

```
input
    id, email_MD5, email_SHA1, idType
    d1, md1,       sh1,        type1
    d2, null,      sh2,        type2
```

I need to transform the table to `source` and `destination` relations according to following logic:

1. If only one of `email_MD5` and `email_SHA1` fields are null it converted to `id`-> `email` relation with original type.
2. If both emails are not nulls it converted to 3 relations: `id`-> `email_MD5` ,  `id`-> `email_SHA1` and the relation between the emails `email_MD5` -> `email_SHA1` with hardcoded type `email`

```
output
    src,  dst, idType
    d1,   md1, type1
    d1,   sh1, type1
    md1,  sh1, email
    d2,   sh2, type2
```

How can I do it in presto and spark sql?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is possible purely with `UNION` all possible combinations:

```sql
SELECT id AS src
,email_SHA1 AS dst
,idType
FROM input
WHERE email_SHA1 is not null
UNION
SELECT id AS src
,email_MD5 AS dst
,idType
FROM input
WHERE email_MD5 is not null
UNION
SELECT email_MD5 AS src
,email_SHA1 AS dst
,'email' AS idType
FROM input
WHERE email_SHA1 is not null and email_MD5 is not null
```

Comment: Thanks, but it request me to scan all data 3 times.